# Monitor database with GWT

Tags: java, mysql, gwt

Maybe I'm overthinking this but I'd like some advice. Customers can place an order inside my GWT application and on a secondary computer I want to monitor those submittals inside th eGWT application and flash an alarm every time an order is submitted, provided the user has OK'd this. I cant figure out the best way to do this. Orders are submitted to a mysql database if that makes any difference. Does anyone have a suggestion on what to do or try?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options: 1) polling or 2) pushing which would allow your server (in the servlet handling the GWT request) to notify you (after the order is successfully placed).

In 1) polling, the client (meaning the browser you are using to monitor the app) will periodically call the server to see if there is data waiting.  It may be more resource intensive as many calls are made for infrequent data.  It may also be slower due to the delay between calls.  If only your monitoring client is calling though it wouldn't be so resource intensive.

In 2) pushing, the client will make a request and the request will be held open until there is data.  It is less resource intensive and can be faster.  Once data is returned, the client sends another request (this is long polling).  Alternatively, streaming is an option where the server doesn't sent a complete request and just keeps sending data.  This streaming option requires a specific client-/browser-specific implementation though.  If it's just you monitoring though, you should know the client and could set it up specifically for that.

See the demo project in [GWT Event Service](https://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/)
Here is the [documentation (user manual)](http://gwteventservice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/Manual.pdf) for it.

Also see [GWT Server Push FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ)

There are other ways of doing it other than GWT Event Service of course.  Just google "GWT server push" and you'll find comet, DWR, etc., and if you are using Google's App Engine [the Channel API](http://googleappengine.blogspot.jp/2010/12/happy-holidays-from-app-engine-team-140.html)